# How do I install curses library in my editor?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-curses

I cannot install the `curses` library in my Editor. Is there some other way to make sure I have the library installed and can import it?

I'm trying to build a tictactoe game using `venv`, in **Pycharm** Community Edition. I imported curses in the directory where my scripts are located using command prompt. I can import `curses` in IDLE editor. However, there is no package called `curses` in the `Settings->Project Interpreter`.

```
pip install curses‑2.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

this throws an error:

> Requirement 'curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a
>   filename, but the file does not exist
>   curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this
>   platform.

Edited the configurations and checked the checkbox with emulate terminal in output console, still won't work.

Comment: What OS and what Python version are you running?

Comment: Windows 10, Python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
pip install https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/n5jyqt7p/curses-2.2.1+utf8-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

The section of the pip command line installer:

```
cp37 == CPython 3.7
```

So you need the appropriate `whl` install file for your installed Python environment.

Comment: uh, it shows,Requirement 'curses-2.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

Comment: Added URL to install from since you don't have it downloaded. You can also download and install from local folder.